# Which pallets cannot be added through a runtime upgrade?

Tags: substrate-node-template, runtime-upgrade

We started our chain using substrate-node-template which is using PoA consensus with Aura for block production. Now we are trying to move to PoS with Babe. We found out that it is not possible to change consensus mechanism mid flight, and we need to restart our chain from block zero. So my question is, what other scenarios are there, where we need a chain restart?

What pallets we cannot simple add and use through a runtime upgrade and storage migration?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is not clear, but you can add any pallet to your runtime unless it is not changing the consensus. Other thing you need to take care of is the epoch time it cannot be changed via runtime upgrade so for that also you need to start your chain again.

Comment: @ShubhamGupta I am just asking what kind of changes other than consensus require us to restart the chain from block zero, and if there are any pallets that can only be added at genesis. And yes I am aware that we cannot change epoch time after chain starts.

Comment: Technically speaking you could migrate your PoA chain to a PoS chain and not have to restart your chain at all.

Comment: @Bruno The main issue is migrating consensus from Aura to Babe, and as far as I understand that is not possible mid flight. And I suppose its possible to have some kind of PoS working woth Aura, but that's not what we wanted.

Comment: You could also run a new chain with PoS and migrate the data from the PoA chain this is doable and would avoid restarts and maintain data integrity -- not easy but it is an option